# Problem performing LayoutAnimation in RecyclerView when triggered by SwipeRefreshLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-animation, swiperefreshlayout

I am trying to perform a custom animation in my RecyclerView using the XML property `android:layoutAnimation`.

The problem is: When I populate my adapter directly in the activity's `onCreate()`, the animation triggers normally. However, when I try to populate my recyclerView from the `SwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener` the animation is not triggered correctly.

I have no idea what is wrong.

### Dependencies

```
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha04'
```

### XML files

Activity XML:

```xml
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/postListRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:layoutAnimation="@anim/layout_animation_enter_up"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp" />
```

layout_animation_enter_up.xml:

```xml
<layoutAnimation
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:animation="@anim/item_animation_enter_up"
    android:animationOrder="normal"
    android:delay="15%" />
```

item_animation_enter_up.xml:

```xml
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="600">

    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="50%p"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
        android:toYDelta="0" />

    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
        android:toAlpha="1" />

</set>
```

### [My Code](https://github.com/phellipealexandre/CoolPosts) in simplified version

This code triggers the *layout_animation_enter_up* animation correctly:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_post_list)

    val adapter = PostsAdapter()
    postListRecyclerView.adapter = adapter
    val dummyData = Post(1, "Title", "Body", 1, "Name")
    val postList = listOf(dummyData, dummyData, dummyData, dummyData, dummyData, dummyData, dummyData)

    adapter.submitList(postList)
}
```

This code **does not** trigger the *layout_animation_enter_up* animation:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    postListSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener {
        val adapter = PostsAdapter()
        postListRecyclerView.adapter = adapter
        val dummyData = Post(1, "Title", "Body", 1, "Name")
        val postList = listOf(dummyData, dummyData, dummyData, dummyData, dummyData, dummyData, dummyData)

        adapter.submitList(postList)
    }
}
```

In both code snippets (that are basically the same), I am considering that the RecyclerView is going **from an empty state to a populated state**. Is there any difference on the UI perspective if I populate my adapter inside the `setOnRefreshListener` callback or inside the `onCreate`?

**Edit**: The snippets above are different from the original codebase just to make the explanation easier. I don't want to know about performance in this question. I would like to know why the animation does not work in the second snippet and works fine in the first snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the first snippet **only** should work if you submit your list inside refresh, i.e:

```
postListSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener {
  adapter.submitList(postList)
}
```

And the second snippet of code should not trigger animation, because every time you refresh layout you create a **new adapter instance** which make the adapter can't observer the changes.

I don't know why you're creating a new instance every time you refresh your layout, however this consuming memory with useless instances.

**In Summary:** You should create instances one time only, and reuse it as much as you can instead of creating new one.

Comment: Hi Ibrahim, thanks for your response. The snippets above are different from the original codebase just to make the explanation easier (I added this info in my post). My intention here is to understand why the animation works in the first snippet and not in the second, considering that the RecyclerView is going from an empty state to a populated state in both cases. I have tried using one instance of the adapter and I still have the same problem  =(

Comment: @PhellipeSilva Well, I think there is no much more potentials here, you're creating new adapter and setting new adapter instance to recycleView which produce non-animation behavior. And by submitting list **only** in `onRefresh` should work if you have submitted different lists items.